# How do I add a double tab in fortran?

Tags: fortran

A line of code like this:

```
write(*,*) a,b
```

will produce as an output `a` and `b` separated by one tab. How can I write an output with `a`and `b` separated by two tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line will typically not produce any tab character, but some number of blank (space) characters. If you want two tab characters, you have to use their ASCII code 9.

```
write(*,'(4g0)') a, achar(9), achar(9), b
```

Note the explicit format `'(4g0)'` used to avoid unwanted blank characters. With the `g0` descriptor it will work for any type of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks, I forgot to change that. My starting point were `a` and `b` character strings but then I realized hey may be numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The <tab>-character is not a part of the Fortran character-set. So when you add it to your source code, most compilers should
complain [[Cfr. Section 3 Fortran 2008 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)].

If you want to add it to your output, you have to create a
character of the requested kind that represents that particular
character. To do this, you make use of `ACHAR(I [, KIND])` which
converts the ASCII code `I` into that particular character of kind
`KIND` or the default kind if `KIND` is not specified. For the
[<tab>-character](http://www.asciitable.com/) this would read:

```
ACHAR(9)
```

Another way, but less preferred, would be to make use of the
`ISO_C_BINDING` module which defines the constant
`C_HORIZNTAL_TAB`. This represents `\t`, a character of the
C-character kind `C_CHAR`. If `C_CHAR=-1`, the constant is converted
to `ACHAR(9)`  [[Cfr. Section 15.2 Fortran 2008 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)]

See [Vladimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55453823/8344060) for the howto.

Comment: ISO 1539-1:2010 section 3.1.6 *"Additional characters may be representable in the processor, but may appear only in comments, character constants, input/output records, and character string edit descriptors."*